# Javascript Pattern to access the global object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, global

i've found this example code

```
    var global = (function () {
      return this || (1, eval)('this');
    }());
```

but i havn't understood its utility. When/why i should use this code?

From: http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/?utm_content=buffer874b9&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=facebook&utm_campaign=Buffer

Comment: You normally don't need this. As simple as that.

Comment: Read the description: `Description: access the global object without hard-coding the identifier window`. Usually (in a browser) the global object is `window`. In some environments (e.g. node JS) it isn't. As @dystroy said, you usually wouldn't need to worry about this.

Comment: In non strict code, there are simpler ways to get the global object. For example `(function(){return this}).call()`.

Comment: @MattBurland Even in a library running both in a browser and in node, a properly designed program has rarely reasons to access the global object (I don't think you say otherwise, just trying to be clearer).

Comment: @dystroy: Absolutely agree. If you need the global object, your first thought should be to rethink what you are doing and come up with a better way.

Comment: @Bergi This doesn't look like the good closing reason as OP already knows how to access the  global object.